# How to add carriage return in python?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a simpl example:

```
test = """test
dsdssd
dsdssd
"""

def html_doc(args):
    return Environment().from_string(test).render(args)

print html_doc({ })
```

How to add "carriage return" (\r)  in the end of each string ?

Comment: Which strings? Do you mean at the end of every *line* of `test`?

Comment: Are you actually sending this to a web browser, or is "html_doc" just horribly named? A newline in HTML is rendered as a space.

Comment: Im guessing he is trying to "view source" and doesnt want it all crammed on one page...

Answer (score 12):

```
test = str.replace(test, '\n', '\r\n')
```

**EDIT:** Python [automatically tries to take care of newlines](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.3.html#pep-278-universal-newline-support) for reading and writing files, but I assume because the question is tagged as jinja2 that this string isn't being written to a file.

Comment: This is misleading at best. "\n"s in Python are already translated to "\r\n" on teh output wherever this is relevant. I am not shure what the O.P. wants as well, but this won't help.

Comment: @jsbueno you're referring to Universal Newline Support (PEP 278), right?